# React: importing map values from Sass

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm trying to import map values from Sass that are passed as props in React. My goal is to have a component that displays a color palette from Sass.

The component that displays the color palette:

```js
<div className="color-box-column">
    {[...Array(21).keys()].map(raw_code => {
        return <ColorPaletteTile backgroundColor={`red-${raw_code*100}`}>Red {raw_code*100}</ColorPaletteTile>
    })}
</div>
```

The component with the tile:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import styles from '../../../styles/color_palette.scss';

function ColorPaletteTile(props){
    return (
        <div className="color-box" style={{backgroundColor: `${styles}.${props.backgroundColor}`}}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}

ColorPaletteTile.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any,
    backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
}

export default ColorPaletteTile;
```

The SCSS for the component:

```scss
$colors: (
    red-0: #FCF5F5,
    red-100: #FFE2E2,
    red-200: #FFCFCD,
    red-300: #FFBCB8,
    red-400: #FFA9A3,
    red-500: #FF958C,
    red-600: #FF8175,
    red-700: #FF6C5E,
    red-800: #FF5545,
    red-900: #FF3A2B,
    red-1000: #FC0A0A,
    red-1100: #E60013,
    red-1200: #D00017,
    red-1300: #BA0019,
    red-1400: #A4001A,
    red-1500: #8F0019,
    red-1600: #790118,
    red-1700: #640316,
    red-1800: #500512,
    red-1900: #3C060C,
    red-2000: #2A0303
);

:export {
    @each $key, $value in $colors {
        #{unquote($key)}: $value;
    }
}
```